# Data about olive fruits, oil, pomace

Tags: data-request

I would like to get the large data set of polyphenols content and antioxidant activity in olive fruits, oil and pomace. Ideally from different countries. Is anyone aware if such data is available?

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked into the USDA Food Composition Database (https://ndb.nal.usda.gov/) and The Canadian Nutrient File (http://www.hc-sc.gc.ca/fn-an/nutrition/fiche-nutri-data/index-eng.php)? Both contain nutrient data about many foods, and it's likely that the ones you are looking for are represented there in some form.

Comment: Thank you. This are good resources. There are displayed data of content of compounds as one averaged  number and I would like to have a diversity by countries.

Comment: Please share if you find similar datasets for other countries - would be useful to know where it is :-)